# Get HttpRequest like Fiddler

Tags: asp.net, fiddler

What's the easiest way to convert the entire HttpWebRequest to a single string. Similarly to what Fiddler displays when you switch the Fiddler's request pane to the Raw tab?

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `System.Net.WebClient`.

This code combines the HTTP Headers and Body for a Url similar to Fiddler:

```
string url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();           
var body = webClient.DownloadString(url);
var headers = webClient.ResponseHeaders.ToString();
var raw = headers + "\r\n" + body;
```